# Python, PySide sleep without stalling the whole program?

Tags: python, user-interface, sleep, pyside

I have this piece of code:

```
 self.connect(self.Yes_button,SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.Yes_pressed)
 self.connect(self.No_button,SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.No_pressed)

def Yes_pressed(self):
    self.Box.append("Hello")
    time.sleep(2)
    self.Box.append("Text2")
```

what it does is when the Yes button is pressed it waits 2 seconds first then appends both Hello and Text2(Box is a QTextBrowser() object)How could I make so it would appending one, wait 2 seconds and append the other one instead? Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: try to call self.update() before the sleep, and tell me if works hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, using `pyqt's` [`Qtimer`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html). More specifically the [`singleShot`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html#singleShot)

Setup : `QTimer.singleShot (int msec, QObject receiver, SLOT()SLOT() member)`

```
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: self.Box.append("Text2")) #1000 milliseconds = 1 second
```

Or you can event try this implementation:

```
    self.timerScreen = QTimer()
    self.timerScreen.setInterval(1000) #1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    self.timerScreen.setSingleShot(True)
    self.timerScreen.timeout.connect(self.Box.append("Text2"))
```

**Part 2**

You can probably do something like this, but I do not recommend it:

```
def testSleep(self):
    self.lineEdit.setText('Start')
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, lambda: self.Box.append("Text2")) 
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000,lambda: self.timerEvent)


def timerEvent(self):
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, lambda: self.Box.append("Text3"))
```

You are better off just doing something like this:

```
x = 10000 #or whatever number
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000 + x, lambda: self.Box.append("Text3"))
```

Comment: I see however I have a problem here that every calculation starts at the same time, so I want it to have an X second pause after each append.

so for example:         
QTimer.singleShot(10000, lambda: self.Box.append("Text2"))
QTimer.singleShot(10000, lambda: self.Box.append("Text3"))

prints both after 10 seconds and I want to be 10 second gab between them without making text3 20000

Comment: So basically, you just want `x + 10000` everytime the function is called between text2 and text3? Thats easy, just check out my edit.

Comment: @Granitas Its simple, the first one with `timerEvent` function just adds 10000 ms to that method which makes a total timeout of (20000 ms), the second one with `x = 10000`, just adds another `x` ms so it will make a total time of `10000 + x` ms, in your case `20000` ms.

Comment: yup, the example with the x should be more than enough. Thank you very much !